# Alamofire Cache not found

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlcache

I have been trying to setup the cache for Alamofire 5.0 by doing the configuration below:

```swift
private func buildURLCache() -> URLCache {
  let capacity = 50 * 1024 * 1024 // MBs
  #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
  return URLCache(memoryCapacity: capacity, diskCapacity: capacity)
  #else
  return URLCache(memoryCapacity: capacity, diskCapacity: capacity, diskPath: nil)
  #endif
}

private func defaultSessionManager(_ requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor?) -> Alamofire.Session {

  let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "google.com": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: pinnedCertificates())
  ]

  // Create custom manager
  let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
  configuration.headers = HTTPHeaders.default
  configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy

  URLCache.shared = buildURLCache()
  configuration.urlCache = URLCache.shared

  return Alamofire.Session(
      configuration: configuration,
      interceptor: requestInterceptor,
      serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators))
}
```

The function `defaultSessionManager(_)` returns a configured instance of `Alamofire`, I put it in as strong reference and do a request like this below (don't worry it's just an example):

```swift
let alamofireManager = defaultSessionManager(nil)

func getFoos(
  token: String,
  completion: @escaping (Result<[Foo], Error>) -> Void) {

  alamofireManager.request(
    "google.com",
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: headers(token))
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (dataResponse: AFDataResponse<Any>) in

      if let cacheData = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: dataResponse.request!) {
        print("URLCache.shared Data is from cache")
      } else {
        print("URLCache.shared Data is from Server")
      }

      if let cacheData = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: (dataResponse.request?.urlRequest!)!) {
        print("URLCache.shared urlRequest Data is from cache")
      } else {
        print("URLCache.shared urlRequest Data is from Server")
      }

      //....
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the functions `URLCache.shared.cachedResponse` are returning `nil`, causing the function to only print `... Data is from Server`. The app is never getting the data from the cache, any idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

First, currently `response.request` returns the last `URLRequest` that *Alamofire* saw, which is not necessarily the `URLRequest` that was performed and went out over the network. To see that value, you'll actually need to capture the Alamofire `Request` and check its `task?.currentRequest` property. That should give you the `URLRequest` that passed through Alamofire and the `URLSession` and was performed. We're looking into making these `URLRequest`s available off the response as well.

Second, if you just want to check whether you received a cached response, it's better to check the `URLSessionTaskMetrics` value, as that should provide a definitive answer without needing to check the `URLCache`.

```swift
response.metrics?.transactionMetrics.last?.resourceFetchType
```

If this value is `.localCache`, then you know your response came from the cache.

Comment: Perfect answer. I tried to set this and check it it is `.localCache` but it keeps returning false. Any suggestion why? I tried to check `alamofireManager.sessionConfiguration.urlCache` and it's not returning `nil`.

Comment: Ultimately the easiest way to confirm whether you're loading from cache or the network is to use a tool like Charles Proxy to intercept your web traffic and see whether the call is being made. That should definitively tell you one way or the other.

Comment: That's not possible, I am not using the cache for debug proposes.

Comment: I meant just to make sure the property is properly indicating whether something is loading from cache, not as a long term solution.

Comment: Based on what the documentation says [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-caching), Alamofire does cache automatically, but both `response.metrics?.transactionMetrics.last?.resourceFetchType` and `task?.currentRequest` solutions are telling me that the app is not using the cached data, is there any reason why? I am not looking for network availability cache but instead a cache to prevent unnecessary transfer of data in the requests.

Comment: Alamofire doesn't do any caching itself. Instead it relies on `URLSession` and the underlying `URLCache` to cache `URLRequest`s based on the request's `cachePolicy`. By default that value is `.useProtocolCachePolicy`, which will cache responses based on the server's configuration, like caching headers. If you want to always cache responses, regardless of the server configuration, you'll need to change that value, either per request or for the `URLSessionConfiguration`.

Comment: I tried again to add the headers needed, overriding things based on what you told me: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/e36bbc69410bb97ec368d38727ded9eb

It keeps not caching the response :(

Comment: Caching only works if the server returns proper responses to enable caching, unless you brute force it. You can try setting it to `.returnCacheDataElseLoad`, which may get what you want, but you lose all server invalidation.

Comment: The server is sending `no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate` but `Expires` is 0. What I was planning to do is to send a HEAD request to the server to verify the content and let the app decide if the data needs to be requested or not. Similar of what the documentation of `CachePolicy.reloadRevalidatingCacheData` says.

Comment: You can also implement a `CachedResponseHandler` in Alamofire to help force the caching. Read more in the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#cachedresponsehandler).